# Is there any C++ lightweight cross-platform file system library?

Tags: c++, api, dll, filesystems

I need a lightweight cross-platform file system library for game development.
I want to ship my games on Windows, Linux and Mac.

As far as I know, using [dirent.h](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/dirent.h.html) works on all three platforms. However, I wanted to know if a library that is simpler to use exists - using directly dirent was confusing for me and I didn't get anywhere.

I also tried Boost, but I don't like the fact that it's not lightweight and it gave me trouble on Unix ports of my game.

Features I require are:

- Recursively read directory trees
- Get all files in a directory
- Get all sub-directories in a directory

Comment: Are you asking about the library that provides easier access to the existing filesystem OR about the library that implements a filesystem (container)?

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I'm asking about a library that helps me get existing directories/files in the hard drive. For example, I want to get all the .png files in "C:/MyGame/Data/Images" without much hassle.

Comment: Have you checked your GUI framework (you are writing a game, right?)? Sometimes they tend to include extra stuff like filesystem api.

Comment: @hate-engine I'm using SFML, and unfortunately it does not include a filesystem api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created my own file system library (tested on Windows and Linux, both with GCC and Clang).

You can find it in the SSVUtils library:
https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils

SSVUtils has no external dependencies.

Example usage:

```
log("Getting all page.json files", "loadPages");

string pagesPath("Json/Pages/");
vector<string> pageJsonPaths{getScan<Mode::Recurse, Type::File, Pick::ByName>(pagesPath, "page.json")};
```